# "CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME AS" vs. "CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME AS BEGIN/END"

Tags: t-sql

When creating a stored procedure, does the BEGIN/END block serve and purpose?

eg,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME
AS
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

vs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [CREATE PROCEDURE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx), the BEGIN/END is optional:

> { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ]
>   [ END ] }
>
> One or more Transact-SQL
>   statements comprising the body of the
>   procedure. You can use the optional
>   BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the
>   statements. For information, see the
>   Best Practices, General Remarks, and
>   Limitations and Restrictions sections
>   that follow.

As a matter of personal preference, I always include them.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it is just an unnecessary extra indent level.  However, if you make it a `BEGIN TRY` - `END TRY` with a `BEGIN CATCH` - `END CATCH` then it adds a real purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is just a good style of programming and following general standards.They don't differ in anything as far as I know.

I  personally think it makes sense and improves readability to have a `BEGIN` and `END` around every logical chunk of code (even in stored procedures case).

Comment: `a BEGIN and END around every logical chunk of code`, yikes! I think that would get it the way more that it would help.

Comment: Well I see your point..I was trying to point out the best practices..I would not have it for one liners or trivial places...

Answer (score 0):

There is no real pourpose in the case. But your code will be readable and clean if you use BEGIN/END blocks.

Comment: I've seen lots of code with BEGIN/END blocks that wasn't very readable.  There is a lot more to readable code than just using BEGIN/END blocks everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The BEGIN and END have no bearing for a stored procedure, however they *are* required for a Function.

Okay:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.sproc(@v varchar(10))
AS
RETURN -1
```

Not okay:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fun(@v varchar(10))
RETURNS INT
AS
RETURN 1
```